# trying to get a rocket to run (doesnt work :()

Tags: javascript

So i'm currently partaking in some tasks for my school and then i came across one of them which got me a bit confused! We are asked to make the rocket launch however i am confused on how i would go about this. Hopefully, you can help me do this and thanks for reading.

```
            // Launch the rocket!
            var launchRocket = function (sequence) {
                if (sequence != 321) {
                var _$_f307 = ["\x63\x6C\x61\x73\x73\x4E\x61\x6D\x65", "\x61\x6E\x69\x6D\x61\x74\x69\x6F\x6E\x2D\x77\x69\x6E\x64\x6F\x77", "\x67\x65\x74\x45\x6C\x65\x6D\x65\x6E\x74\x73\x42\x79\x43\x6C\x61\x73\x73\x4E\x61\x6D\x65", "\x62\x6F\x64\x79", "\x61\x6E\x69\x6D\x61\x74\x69\x6F\x6E\x2D\x77\x69\x6E\x64\x6F\x77\x20\x61\x6E\x69\x6D\x61\x74\x65", "\x66\x69", "\x72\x33\x61", "\x77\x61\x79", "\x69\x6E\x6E\x65\x72\x48\x54\x4D\x4C", "\x72\x6F\x63\x6B\x65\x74\x2D\x63\x6F\x64\x65"];
                document[_$_f307[3]][_$_f307[2]](_$_f307[1])[0][_$_f307[0]] = _$_f307[4];
                var e = _$_f307[5];
                var x = _$_f307[6];
                var n = _$_f307[7];
                document[_$_f307[3]][_$_f307[2]](_$_f307[9])[0][_$_f307[8]] = e + x + n;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Rockets, usually, don't run... They fly...

Comment: What is the code doing and what do you want it to do?

Comment: Well this one is looking to become Usain Bolt!

Comment: Hi Trevor,

I've got no idea what the code is doing otherwise i think i'd be able to figure it out and im looking for it to move and then display a code.

Comment: What is that code? Where did you find it? How is it relevant?

Comment: The code is made to launch a rocket.

Our school signed us up for a website called "CyberDiscovery" and we were told to do the tasks

And it is relevant because it is needed for one of the tasks

Comment: There is not enough information here for anyone to answer, (it's missing the rest of the relevant code) and as this is apparently homework you should be trying solutions on your own, not just asking people on the internet to make it work. If you run into a specific problem (eg, an error that you don't understand, a question about how to use a certain function, etc) then you can search for answers here or ask about it yourself if it hasn't already been asked.

Comment: Do `launchRocket();` and you're all set!

Comment: Hi there Sani, where would i put that?

Comment: Hero, i've already contacted a web developer and 2 system admins who work with javascript on the daily none of them understand

Comment: @DiscoBot If you've only told them exactly what you posted in your question and comments here then it's no wonder they don't understand.

Comment: @Herohtar I've been in a Skype call with them for about 2 hours now, we've been trying to run all types of Source Snippets and edit the code to make it work but we can't find anything :/

Comment: Well, if that is true, I'm not sure how you expect anyone here to be able to help you with the information given. In its current state, your question is unanswerable.

Comment: There is most likely some missing information in your script. I used it and it did absolutely nothing. The Cyber Discovery site is probably linking the script to some external script that you do not know.

Answer (score 0):

All these `\xXX` are Hex codes of letters. Just decode them to see

```
var _$_f307 = [//create array
   "className", //[0]
   "animation-window", 
   "getElementsByClassName", 
   "body", 
   "animation-window animate", 
   "fi", 
   "r3a", 
   "way", 
   "innerHTML", 
   "rocket-code" //[9]
];
//then replace other cipher with values

//document[_$_f307[3]][_$_f307[2]](_$_f307[1])[0][_$_f307[0]] = _$_f307[4];
document["body"]["getElementsByClassName"]("animation-window")[0]["className"] = "animation-window animate";

var e = _$_f307[5]; //fi
var x = _$_f307[6]; //r3a
var n = _$_f307[7]; //way
//document[_$_f307[3]][_$_f307[2]](_$_f307[9])[0][_$_f307[8]] = e + x + n;
document["body"]["getElementsByClassName"]("rocket-code")[0]["innerHTML"] = e + x + n; //fir3away
```

Note that you can address JS object properties using dot `.` or bracket `[]` syntax.

So add rocket launcher ;)

```
<div class="animation-window"></div>
<div class="rocket-code"></div>
```

**Update** See working example

```js
// Launch the rocket!
var launchRocket = function(sequence) {
  if (sequence != 321) {
    var _$_f307 = ["\x63\x6C\x61\x73\x73\x4E\x61\x6D\x65", "\x61\x6E\x69\x6D\x61\x74\x69\x6F\x6E\x2D\x77\x69\x6E\x64\x6F\x77", "\x67\x65\x74\x45\x6C\x65\x6D\x65\x6E\x74\x73\x42\x79\x43\x6C\x61\x73\x73\x4E\x61\x6D\x65", "\x62\x6F\x64\x79", "\x61\x6E\x69\x6D\x61\x74\x69\x6F\x6E\x2D\x77\x69\x6E\x64\x6F\x77\x20\x61\x6E\x69\x6D\x61\x74\x65", "\x66\x69", "\x72\x33\x61", "\x77\x61\x79", "\x69\x6E\x6E\x65\x72\x48\x54\x4D\x4C", "\x72\x6F\x63\x6B\x65\x74\x2D\x63\x6F\x64\x65"];
    console.log(_$_f307);
    document[_$_f307[3]][_$_f307[2]](_$_f307[1])[0][_$_f307[0]] = _$_f307[4];
    var e = _$_f307[5];
    var x = _$_f307[6];
    var n = _$_f307[7];
    document[_$_f307[3]][_$_f307[2]](_$_f307[9])[0][_$_f307[8]] = e + x + n;
  }
}
//Call the function
//launchRocket(0);
```

```css
.animate {
  background: red
}
```

```html
<div class="animation-window">Will be red</div>
<div class="rocket-code">code</div>
<button type="button" onclick="launchRocket(0);">Launch!</button>
```

Comment: Hi there Alex, it seems that the dividers you suggested are already in the code. [link](http://dlgames.co.uk/imgs/aptkc6nHJZ.png)